# Dual of a function space with different regularity on the two variables

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, duality-theorems

If I have a normed function space $\mathcal{F}(X)$ on $X$, I can always take its dual. In some cases, we can identify the dual with some known space. The most typical example is: for $p\in(1,\infty)$, $\tfrac{1}{p}+\tfrac{1}{q}=1$, and $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^n) = L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}^n)^* = L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

My **question**: we have two function spaces, one $\mathcal{F}_1(X)$ and one $\mathcal{F}_2(Y)$ (we can think of them as $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n, Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$), and we know some representation of their duals $\mathcal{F}_1(X)^*$ and $\mathcal{F}_2(Y)^*$. Let's define another space $\mathcal{F}(X\times Y)$ such that $f\in\mathcal{F}(X\times Y)$ means that $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,\cdot)\in\mathcal{F}_2(Y)$ for all $x$, $f(\cdot,y)\in\mathcal{F}_1(X)$ for all $y$.

For example: $\mathcal{F}_1(X)= L^{p_1}(X)$, $\mathcal{F}_2(Y)=L^{p_2}(Y)$ and $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,\cdot)\in L^{p_2}(Y), \ f(\cdot,y)\in L^{p_1}(X)$.

Can we say something about the dual space $\mathcal{F}(X\times Y)^*$?

(the example with the Lebesgue spaces is mostly there to help with reading the notation; however, I am hoping that something holds with a bit more generality)

Comment: you did not say, what norm you want to put on $F$. in your example, I would expect $(\int_X (\int_Y |f|^{p1}dy)^{p2/p1} dx)^{1/p2}$. then the space is $L^{p_1}(X; L^{p_2}(Y))$, and the dual space is under some assumptions equal to $L^{p_1'}(X; L^{p_2'}(Y*))$